# remove items from the dictionary having a common element in list

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have one dictionary and one list values I want to remove the values from the dictionary if the element is existed in list data , I worked with some methods but some values are not removing, not getting where i did mistake

```
extra_list = ['387', '404', '637', '401', '405', '579', '408', '739', '736', '447', '403', '402', '581']
main_data = [{'stock id': 447, 'name': 'Inners(Essa fai', 'values': 4},
             {'stock id': 757, 'name': 'Designery(Blous', 'values': 2},
             {'stock id': 652, 'name': 'Saree krishna(P', 'values': 1},
             {'stock id': 408, 'name': 'Designery(Blous', 'values': 1},
             {'stock id': 684, 'name': 'Saree(Ikkat pri', 'values': 1}]


def listRemover(main_list, remove_list):
    for j in main_list:
        if str(j['stock id']) in remove_list:
            main_list.remove(j)
    return main_list


data = listRemover(main_data, extra_list)
```

I want remove the dictionary value if the stock id existed in extra list

Comment: You should not modify a list that you are looping over.

Comment: The question would be clearer if you showed what output you are getting, and how it differs from the output that you want, but I would suggest building up a separate list of the items that you want to keep - maybe using a list comprehension.

Comment: Ya thank you I came to know the mistake

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than modifying the input list, create a new list as follows:

```
extra_list = ['387', '404', '637', '401', '405', '579', '408', '739', '736', '447', '403', '402', '581']
main_data = [{'stock id': 447, 'name': 'Inners(Essa fai', 'values': 4},
             {'stock id': 757, 'name': 'Designery(Blous', 'values': 2},
             {'stock id': 652, 'name': 'Saree krishna(P', 'values': 1},
             {'stock id': 408, 'name': 'Designery(Blous', 'values': 1},
             {'stock id': 684, 'name': 'Saree(Ikkat pri', 'values': 1}]


def listRemover(main_list, remove_list):
    s = set(map(int, remove_list))
    return [j for j in main_list if j.get('stock id') not in s]

print(listRemover(main_data, extra_list))
```

**Output:**

```
[{'stock id': 757, 'name': 'Designery(Blous', 'values': 2}, {'stock id': 652, 'name': 'Saree krishna(P', 'values': 1}, {'stock id': 684, 'name': 'Saree(Ikkat pri', 'values': 1}]
```

Answer (score 1):

I would create a new list in memory of what you want to keep. As stated in the comments it's a bad idea to modiy a list your looping over

```
def listRemover(main_list, remove_list):
    new_list = []
    for j in main_list:
        if not (str(j['stock id']) in remove_list):
            new_list.append(j)
    return new_list


data = listRemover(main_data, extra_list)
```

Output

```
[{'stock id': 757, 'name': 'Designery(Blous', 'values': 2}, {'stock id': 652, 'name': 'Saree krishna(P', 'values': 1}, {'stock id': 684, 'name': 'Saree(Ikkat pri', 'values': 1}]
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran your code and printed data, which gave me:

```
[{'stock id': 757, 'name': 'Designery(Blous', 'values': 2}, {'stock id': 652, 'name': 'Saree krishna(P', 'values': 1}, {'stock id': 684, 'name': 'Saree(Ikkat pri', 'values': 1}]
```

so I guess it worked.

However, removing objects from a list you're iterating over is usually not the best idea. You could do

```
for j in copy.deepcopy(main_list):
```

instead of:

```
for j in main_list:
```

just to be safe.

Comment: Can you elaborate to show how you think this might work

Comment: Well, obviously it won't. Thank you for pointing that out, I did not what I meant. I edited my comment accordingly.

Comment: Issue is conformed , I did mistake by editing the iteration of list, this is sample data for idea purpose, By the Mistake is solved thank You